# Change HTML lang from en-US in to sr-RS in WordPress - Change font style

Tags: php, html, wordpress, fonts

When I change the language to `sr-RS`, the font style changes.
Here's an example `en-US`:

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <a>Тест фонта</a>
    </body>
<html>
```

**Display font:**
[image: en-US] 
When change to `sr_RS` the font style changes.

```
<html lang="sr-RS">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <a>Тест фонта</a>
    </body>
<html>
```

**Display font:**
[image: sr-RS]

**How can I change the language to sr-RS, but keep the font style with en-US?**

Comment: Try removing cyrillic subset from src: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @AmitRahav Font has Cyrillic. The only problem is that on lang:'sr-RS' shows different font.
This is how the font should look, as it is on lang:'en-US'
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` at the end of the css value? some times browsers have a default setting that over ride the costume css.

Comment: font-language-override for the standard (only FF as of writing). -- developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override -- and -webkit-locale at stackoverflow.com/a/77702242/2344083

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use `-webkit-locale` in CSS:

```css
[lang=sr-RS] * {
    -webkit-locale: "en";
}
```

I have no idea if this affects how screen readers interpret the content though.